# Pure HTML Chart Won't Appear in Gmail When Sent Through Zapier

Tags: html, email, charts, pie-chart, zapier

I am using Zapier in order to schedule monthly emails that are populated with data from GoogleSheets. The data is very simple; it has components- the rating (i.e. 4.5/5) and the % on-time (i.e. 89%).

In Zapier, you can only send an email through gmail, which requires that any code you write be in HTML.

I wanted to find a way to visually represent my data. I want the representation to be dynamic and automatically updated, so creating images of charts is not an option (these emails are going to ~40 people).

Thus, I decided to code a pure HTML chart. However, when I use the code (found off the internet and not modified at all at the moment), the pie chart does not appear on my Gmail on Chrome or Safari on my computer. It does, however, appear on my iPhone in the Mail App but not in the Gmail App.

Here is the code for the pie chart in particular:

```
<head>
  <title> Pie </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>
​

<style>
    .pieContainer {
          height: 100px;
     }
     .pieBackground {
          background-color: grey;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          -o-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
          -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
          -o-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
          box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
     }
     .pie {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          -o-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
     }
     .hold {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          -o-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
     }
​
     #pieSlice1 .pie {
          background-color: #1b458b;
          -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(150deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(150deg);
          transform:rotate(150deg);
     }
     #pieSlice2 {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(150deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(150deg);
          transform:rotate(150deg);
     }
     #pieSlice2 .pie {
          background-color: #ccbb87;
          -webkit-transform:rotate(40deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(40deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(40deg);
          transform:rotate(40deg);
     }
     #pieSlice3 {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(190deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(190deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(190deg);
          transform:rotate(190deg);
     }
     #pieSlice3 .pie {
          background-color: #cc0000;
          -webkit-transform:rotate(70deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(70deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(70deg);
          transform:rotate(70deg);
     }
     #pieSlice4 {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(260deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(260deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(260deg);
          transform:rotate(260deg);
     }
     #pieSlice4 .pie {
          background-color: #cc00ff;
          -webkit-transform:rotate(100deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(100deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(100deg);
          transform:rotate(100deg);
     }
</style>
​
<div class="pieContainer">
     <div class="pieBackground"></div>
     <div id="pieSlice1" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
     <div id="pieSlice2" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
     <div id="pieSlice3" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
     <div id="pieSlice4" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
</div>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this chart to appear in Gmail and not just in the Mail App? All of the people looking at this email will be doing so from their gmail accounts.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re using some newer CSS properties that aren’t supported in the most popular email clients. While your CSS will render nicely when viewed it in a browser, it may not necessarily render well in an email.

Email tends to lag behind browsers when it comes to adopting support for new, fancy CSS properties. Campaign Monitor put together [this handy breakdown](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) of CSS support across several popular email clients. You’ll see that GMail doesn’t support `box-shadow`, `clip`, or `position`, all of which you’re using in your code. While not listed in that guide, the `transform` property is [still in the experimental stage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). This means that it likely won’t be supported in any email clients for at least a few more years, if ever.

When writing HTML for e-mail, I suggest running it through an email tester tool. My personal favorite is PutsMail (free): https://putsmail.com/tests/new.